# Help understanding this connected graph equation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions, connectedness

So in this equation:

The number of connected labeled bipartite graphs with bipartition (X,Y) where |X|=m and 
|Y|=n is the coefficient of $x^my^n/m!\,n!$ in
$$\log\biggl(\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty 2^{mn} \frac{x^m}{m!}\frac{y^n}{n!}\biggr).$$

I am not exactly sure what is going on here.
The equation is supposed to yield this sequence:
[A123260](http://oeis.org/A123260)

For example T(2, 2) = 5.

So I try

for (m,n) =(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)
$$
2^{mn} * \frac{x^m}{m!}*\frac{y^n}{n!}$$

and then add all of the products and get 26. Log(26) does not equal 5. Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you want to formally compose with the series for $\log(1+z)$. This is just an offhand comment I must admit to not having thought about the counting problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a power series $A(x)$ with known coefficients and with constant term 1.
You want the coefficients of the series $B(x)=\log(A(x))$. Taking derivatives
yields
$$
    B'(x) = A'(x)/A(X)    
$$
and hence
$$
    B'(x)A(x) = A'(x)
$$
Assume the coefficients of $x^k$ in $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are $a_k/k!$ and $b_k/k!$.
Then the coefficient of $x^k$ in the LHS is
$$
    \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{b_{i+1}}{i!} \frac{a_{k-i}}{(k-i)!} 
$$
and in the RHS it is
$$
    \frac{a_{k+1}}{k!}.
$$
This gives us a recursion: we know $b_0=0$ and $b_1=1$ and if we have $b_1,\ldots,b_k$, we can compute $b_{k+1}$.